# Separate everyone's phones & our Mac from receiving everyone's texts while sharing the same account?

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, apple-id

I want to share our account because we both use the reminders, photos, notes, etc., and when I tried to set up a new apple ID, it nearly took those away.  I, or he, would've lost our notes, etc.  I don't want to lose stuff, and I was able to separate them before the latest big upgrade back in 2014.  Surely I can do this again.  Same ID, but different, separate users.  How is it done?  Please and thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The apple ID *is* the user.  At some point you'll need to bite the bullet and create new apple IDs for each user if you want separate texts/email accounts etc.

My wife and I use a multitude of applications that can share data across accounts, like

- Anylist for reminders/grocery lists, etc (this can be integrated with the Reminders app
- Photostream for photos
- Google Docs for notes

Also, since iOS 8 you've been able to share applications purchased on any apple ID as long as they have the same credit card on file - so if my wife buys an application, I can download it for free, and vice versa.  It's unfortunate that they still don't support sharing app data, but maybe that's in the works.  Regardless, you will continue to run into problems down the road if you don't separate out your accounts with new Apple IDs.